# Efficiently create Rectangular 2D Array from Multiple 1D

Tags: c#, .net

Aside from looping.  Is there an efficient way to instantiate a 2D array from multiple 1D arrays.

My 1D arrays must behave as column vectors in my 2D rectangular array.  So Column 0 = First 1D array, Column 1 = Second 1D Array, etc...

I've also tried `System.Buffer.BlockCopy`, but block copy will roll the single 1D array into multiple columns which is not what I want.

Simple example of how I want to transform:

```
var c1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var c2 = new int[] {5, 6, 7, 8};
var result = new int[,]
            {{1,5},
             {2,6},
             {3,7},
             {4,8}};
```

Comment: The fastest way is not to do it at all.
Just roll a wrapper with it's own indexer ontop of it IMO. or do you _have to_ have an array for some 3rd party integration/api?

Answer (score 0):

Looping with `unsafe` code and pointers will be the fasted approach that C# can offer. Use `unsafe` because it eliminates the bounds checking which cannot be eliminated in this case b the current JIT.

Loop sequentially through the 2D array in memory order when writing. This means that you need to write row-by-row instead of column-by-column. This trick optimizes memory access and allows you to just increment the write pointer instead of calculating the address each time (`y*width+y`).

Comment: You could eliminate the bounds checking by enclosing your code into the `unchecked` clause.

Comment: @AgentFire unchecked turns off overflow checks, not bounds check. You *cannot* turn off bounds checks alas.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from looping this will do(since you did not specify this as also a no solution):

```
            var c1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            var c2 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            var c3 = new int[,]
            {
                {c1[0],c2[0]},
                {c1[1],c2[1]},
                {c1[2],c2[2]},
                {c1[3],c2[3]}
            };
```